# NDSolve::dvlen: The function \[Theta][t] does not have the same number of arguments as independent variables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

please help me to see what wrong with my code?

```
s = NDSolve[{(m*g*
   Sin[\[Theta][t]]) - (m*(r''[t] - r ((\[Theta]'[t])^2))) == 
k (r[t] - 14),  g*Cos[\[Theta][t]] == 
r[t] \[Theta]''[t] + 2*r'[t] \[Theta]'[t], \[Theta]'[0] == 0, 
 r'[0] == 0}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 60}, {k, 0, 2000}]
```

i want to solve this two equation to find equation of r[t]. I've already set up m and g

Comment: Both `theta` and `r` are shown as functions of only `t` but you specify both `t` and `k` in the sequence of arguments.

Comment: `NDSolve` requests that all functions are functions of all arguments.

Comment: Also, by `r ((\[Theta]'[t])^2)` do you intend `r[t]((\[Theta]'[t])^2)` or ``r[(\[Theta]'[t])^2]`

Comment: if i want to plot r[t] vs theta[t] how to plot